# PhoneGAP Accessing C++ Library on Android Platform

Tags: android, cordova

I need make one call to a C++ library from my HTML5 PhoneGAP application on the Android Platform.  What is the best way to invoke the C++ Library?  Do I need to first wrap in JNI? Note I am not accessing anything Android specific.  Just using a C++ library.  Now I know for Android there is possibility to write custom phonegap plugin, but in this case I need to pull in C++ library so not sure if plugin would work for this.

Answer (score 1):

This one could get a bit complicated. Pardon my ignorance about PhoneGAP, but assuming you have some Java code executing, you should be able to use JNI calls. But you can't make JNI calls to C++ classes and you may have trouble making JNI calls to C++ functions (for obvious reasons, functions with templates will not work, and C++ functions will have name mangling.)

So, before you can access the library via JNI, you probably need to make a C interface on top of the C++ one that you can call into.

Comment: would seem to be a common need to connect to a C++ library.

Comment: Not all that common. Things like the GLES2 implementation and many system-level libraries are written in C. C++ templates are a good example of the problem: for every set of types you instantiate a template with, a new class or function is compiled. So without the header file and a compiler, you can't instantiate a C++ template (class or function.) C++ name mangling and differences between C++ class ABIs makes things worse... In general, to interface with C++ outside of C++, you need to wrap your C++ code into C code and interface with that.

Comment: John.  It seems that it is possible to include C++ with greater feature set since NDK r5.  However it appears to expect a .a file as PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY.